# Why does Int64.MaxValue return a Long?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

Huh that's **ironic** ,while playing around today i wondered if a can Increase Int64.MaxValue on some way ,and just founded out that Int64.MaxValue isn't an Int64 but a Long .

Why is that ,does it mean if i store like `Int64 myInt = Int64.MaxValue;` than myInt will be still an Int or it will become a Long ,what's the purpose of storing a Long Instead of `Int64` at this Field .

Comment: Side note: you can't increase or decrease MaxValue. It doesn't limit Int64 (or any other type that has a MaxValue), it's more of an indicator of how big that type can be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because Int64 and long are same type.

```
Int64 = long    
Int32 = int    
Int16 = short
```

Answer (score 9):

`long` is a synonym of `Int64`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

`long` is just an alias for `Int64`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

From the language specification:

> The members of a simple type correspond directly to the members of the struct type aliased by the simple type:
>
> •  The members of `long` are the members of the `System.Int64` struct.

You can see additional aliases in §3.4.2.

And from 4.1.4:

> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types. The simple types are identified through reserved words, but these reserved words are simply aliases for predefined struct types in the System namespace, as described in the table below.

```
Reserved word Aliased type
long          System.Int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Int64 is a long:

```
        Type t1 = typeof(Int64);
        Type t2 = typeof(long);
        bool same = t1.Equals(t2);  // true
```

Check out MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's `Int16`, `Int32`, and `Int64` that are aliased to `short`, `int`, and `long` respectively. Note that the number is how many bits are used to store the value.